# Strongloop loopback: how to set up a model to store multimedia?

Tags: multimedia, strongloop, loopback

Could someone give me an example of a model named "Multimedia.json" that I could use to store uploaded multimedia files (audio, video, or jpg)?  Specifically, is there a type called "multimedia" or "binary"?  Any strategies the Strongloop way?
Thanks,

```
{
  "name": "Multimedia",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "title": {
      "type": "string",
      "required":true
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "category": {
      "type": "string"  ---can this be a type called binary?
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "report": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Report",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in way to do this, but StrongLoop themselves refer to this post in their documentation for the current best method to store metadata with the storage component.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31118294/1753891
https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Storage+component