# Upload a file to server using loopback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, upload, loopbackjs

I am new to loopback, I want to upload a file using loopback, for this I'm using `container.upload()` function but I am not sure what parameters are passed to this function.

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Comment: @Vineet It is a post method to upload a file using "upload" model and i want code

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28885282/how-to-store-files-with-meta-data-in-loopback