# How to check file format before uploading a file in container using loopback-component-storage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, file-upload, loopbackjs

I have tried this way [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28885282/how-to-store-files-with-meta-data-in-loopback?answertab=votes#tab-top).
I can successfully upload the file, but before that I have to validate file type and allow only *.csv files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mime node module for that.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime

Answer (score 0):

You must complement [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28885282/how-to-store-files-with-meta-data-in-loopback?answertab=votes#tab-top) as follows:

1. Edit `server/datasources.json`, add to storage datasources 
   the `allowedContentTypes` field, an array of [mime types](http://mimeapplication.net/) that you want support

   ```
   ...
    "storage": {
        "name": "storage",
        "connector": "loopback-component-storage",
        "provider": "filesystem", 
        "root": "/var/www/storage",
        "maxFileSize": "52428800",
        "allowedContentTypes":["text/csv", "application/vnd.ms-excel"]
    }
   ...
   ```
2. This step is **optional** but is a good practice. The error can be handled in callback, also can add a [remote hook](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Remote-hooks.html) in the container model file `common/models/container.js`

   ```
    module.exports = function (container) {
      container.afterRemoteError('upload', function (ctx, next) {
       //do any with ctx.error
     });
    }
   ```