# LoopBack Storage Service: how to use upload/download methods from js code?

Tags: javascript, express, loopbackjs

How can I upload/download files in the simplest way using *storageService.upload* and *storageService.download* function from my JavaScript/Loopback code? I'm trying do something like that:

```
app.post("/sendFile", (req, res) => client.upload( req, res, {}, () => {console.log("cb")} ) );
```

But this doesn't work. I make my REST request with Advanced Rest Client Application in Google Chrome. I set *Content-Type* for *multipart-form-data* and add my jpg file in files section.

I got *Failed to create a multipart upload on S3: {"message":"Missing required key 'Bucket' in params","stack":"MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'Bucket' in params (...)* error.

I'm newbie here, but I have impression that [Loopback documentation](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback-component-storage/#storageservice-prototype-upload) should be much better. Thanks for help!

Comment: Have you done any research on that error message? It seems rather clear.

Comment: Yeah, I understand the error, but - to be honest - I don't know where to specify this Bucket thing [I've tried to do that in form, in option parameter etc., but it don't work], documentation isn't very helpful.

Comment: It would go somewhere in your loopback config files.

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same error, and fixed by adding a property to the req-object with your bucket name, before calling .upload() - like so:

```
app.post("/sendFile", (req, res) => {
  req.params.container = "name-of-your-bucket";
  client.upload( req, res, {}, (err, fileObject) => {});
});
```

Or an perhaps even better way if you are going to define some options:

```
app.post("/sendFile", (req, res) => {

  var options = {
    container: "name-of-your-bucket"
  };

  client.upload( req, res, options, (err, fileObject) => {});
});
```

To make upload/download work with Loopback I recommend [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31118294/2804903)