# How do I create models with image field in strongloop(loopback) framework(REST API)

Tags: node.js, rest, loopbackjs, api-design

Here is sample model with image field

```
MyModel {
  model:string
  color:string
  mymodel_image:string  // <= here the image field 
    //is designed to be string like http://domian.com/api/images/dasfs05fsd44f,png
  ...
  }
```

The problem I am facing is creating(writing) this  model(with imagefield) on loopback.
Here are the two approach I have tried so far

1. Uploading the image first and get imageurl as a responce then post
   ***MyModel*** data with this ***imageurl*** that is **two** http requests.  This approach is  not conivinet because network failure(in one of the requests) might causes full process fail.
2. Another way is a single  http request with multipart form data here is what I tried to do that
   upload  the image with ***operation hook before save*** then continue creating MyModel

   ```
   MyModel.observe('before save',function (ctx, next) {
   //do the file  upload here and get file resource url as a result
   //some thing  like this :
        Container.upload(data,options,function (err,fileObj) {   
               File.create({
                name: fileInfo.name,
                type: fileInfo.type,
                container: fileInfo.container,
                url: CONTAINERS_URL+fileInfo.container+'/download/'+fileInfo.name
    } ...);

      //update tee request body and execute the next  
       //callback(creating MyModel)
       //like: req.body.mymodel_image = imageurl
            next();
   ```

   });

the problem with this approach is I can't ***access the request object*** inside the opration hook(because the the ctx parameter does not contain request object).

I need a suggestion  about the overall process and how can I workaround models with image field.

NB: I have handled storing the metadata as mentioned in [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28885282/how-to-store-files-with-meta-data-in-loopback).

Answer (score 0):

What about making a remote (custom) endpoint such as `POST api/MyModel/upload`

Something along the lines of :

```
MyModel.prototype.upload = function (ctx,options,cb) {
    if(!options) options = {};

    Container.upload(data,options,function (err,fileObj) {   
        File.create({
         name: fileInfo.name,
         type: fileInfo.type,
         container: fileInfo.container,
         url: CONTAINERS_URL+fileInfo.container+'/download/'+fileInfo.name  
      }, function(err, file) {
         //.. Create 
      });

  };

  MyModel.remoteMethod(
      'upload',
      {
          isStatic: false,
          description: 'Uploads a file',
          accepts: [
              { arg: 'ctx', type: 'object', http: { source:'context' } },
              { arg: 'options', type: 'object', http:{ source: 'query'} }
          ],
          returns: {
              arg: 'fileObject', type: 'object', root: true
          },
          http: {path: '/MyModel/upload', verb: 'post'}
      }
    );
```

Comment: I just want to override the default create method.