# fetch - Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api, form-data

I want to send a `new FormData()` as the `body` of a `POST` request using the [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

The operation looks something like this:

```js
var formData = new FormData()
formData.append('myfile', file, 'someFileName.csv')

fetch('https://api.myapp.com', 
  {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    },
    body: formData
  }
)
```

The problem here is that the boundary, something like

```
boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryyEmKNDsBKjB7QEqu
```

never makes it into the `Content-Type:` header

It should look like this:

```
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryyEmKNDsBKjB7QEqu
```

When you try the "same" operation with a `new XMLHttpRequest()`, like so:

```js
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
request.open("POST", "https://api.mything.com")
request.withCredentials = true
request.send(formData)
```

the headers are correctly set

```
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryyEmKNDsBKjB7QEqu
```

So my questions are:

1. how do I make `fetch` behave exactly like `XMLHttpRequest` in this situation?
2. if this is not possible, why?

Thanks everybody! This community is more or less the reason I have professional success.

Answer (score 236, accepted):

The solution to the problem is to explicitly set `Content-Type` to `undefined` so that your browser or whatever client you're using can set it and add that boundary value in there for you. Disappointing but true.

Comment: using fetch, I removed the Content-Type header and it worked.

Comment: Unbelievable!! I spent hours until I found this!! `delete result.headers['Content-Type'];` worked for me, thanks!!

Comment: doesn't work for me. Setting to undefined defaults to text/plain.

Comment: @sebnukem which browser? I've never seen that happen, I'll admit though, I switched over to using Axios, it has a nicer api / behavior imo

Comment: @James No problem with the browser. I found out that the HTTP library I was using coerced the body payload to a string.

Comment: @sebnukem which http lib was that? this post is about `fetch`

Comment: @James, an in-house, proprietary lib

Comment: But why is it so?

Comment: @Green Apparently you can define an arbitrary boundary -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data -- I just didn't, I only set the content type, but that is only half the job. On the other hand, If you just leave the content type alone, the browser can infer it, and set the type + the boundary to an appropriate compliant, random string for you.

Comment: Neither setting the content-type to undefined, nor deleting the content-type before making the POST with fetch did it for me...

Comment: 2 years later, I'd recommend using something like axios unless you absolutely need isomorphic fetch - over the years I've found fetch to be more of a nuisance than a help

Comment: Setting value to undefined didn't work for me, but removing header worked :)

Comment: explicitly setting `Content-Type` to `undefined` worked for me

Comment: Setting the Content-Type header to undefined seemed to come across for me as "Content-Type": undefined in the request itself. not defining it worked.

Comment: @James thx man.. you save my live.. I was suffering and looking for a solution to this problem two days ago.. thx again!!

Answer (score 24):

I had the same issue, and was able to fix it by excluding the `Content-Type` property, allowing the browser to detect and set the boundary and content type automatically.

Your code becomes:

```
var formData = new FormData()
formData.append('myfile', file, 'someFileName.csv')

fetch('https://api.myapp.com',
  {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
  }
)
```

Answer (score 19):

I removed "Content-Type" and added  'Accept' to http headers and it worked for me. Here are the headers I used,

```
'headers': new HttpHeaders({
        // 'Content-Type': undefined,
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Authorization': 
        "Bearer "+(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('token')).token),
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': this.apiURL,
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'origin,X-Requested-With,content-type,accept',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true' 

      })
```

Comment: No other solutions worked for me. After adding  Accept: */* header, everything worked like a charm.

Comment: This was exactly it - for Angular 15, leaving out the Content-Type just got it set somewhere else in Angular as a default `undefined`, however, explicitly only providing the `Accept` header excluded the `Content-Type` header, and now I'm home free! Great solution!

Answer (score 15):

```
fetch(url,options)
```

1. If you set a string as `options.body`, you have to set the `Content-Type` in request header ,or it will be `text/plain` by default.
2. If options.body is specific object like `let a = new FormData()` or `let b = new URLSearchParams()`, you don't have to set the `Content-Type` by hand.It will be added automaticlly.

   - for `a` ,it will be something like

   `multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW`

   as you see, the boundary is automaticlly added.

   - for `b`, it is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded;`

Comment: Very well that you told us that `boundary` is added automatically. We have all known that before.

Comment: your explanation makes much more sense, thank you! I managed to get my code working!

Answer (score 13):

According to [FormData documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects#sending_files_using_a_formdata_object), you shoudn't manually set the `Content-Type` header so browser itself will set it correctly:

> Warning: When using FormData to submit POST requests using XMLHttpRequest or the Fetch_API with the multipart/form-data Content-Type (e.g. when uploading Files and Blobs to the server), do not explicitly set the Content-Type header on the request. Doing so will prevent the browser from being able to set the Content-Type header with the boundary expression it will use to delimit form fields in the request body.

So if your code (or library/middleware/etc) manually set the `Content-Type`, you have two ways to fix it:

1. rewrite your code (or whatever you use) to don't set `Content-Type` by default
2. set `Content-Type` to `undefined` or remove it from `headers` to let your browser do it's work

Answer (score 6):

Add `headers:{content-type: undefined}` browser will generate a boundary for you 
that is for uploading a file part-and-part with streaming 
if you are adding 'multiple/form-data' it means you should create streaming and upload your file part-and-part

So it is okay to add request.headers = {content-type: undefined}

Answer (score 4):

I'm using the [aurelia-api](https://aurelia-api.spoonx.org/) (an wrapper to aurelia-fetch-client). 
In this case the Content-Type default is 'application/json'. So I **set the Content-Type to undefined** and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I just use axios and it fixed without any special parameters. the node fetch really sucks