# Not able to change Content-Type in xmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript

I have tried to set the Content-Type before send the xhr data as below

```
function uploadFile() {
  var files =  document.getElementById("file1") .files[0] ;
  var formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append("Key", files);
  ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
  ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
  ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
  ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);  
  ajax.open("POST", "./Save");  
  ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data;'); 
  ajax.send(formdata);
}
```

By changing the content-type, i am not able to get the datas in server end.

If i remove the code for setting the content-type, its working properly

My server side code is below

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["Key"]
```

Is any suggesions?

Comment: try removing the semicolon in `'multipart/form-data;'`

Comment: Hi @Dummy, Already i have tried it but it doesn't work. 
It works only when removing the Content-Type changing code.

Comment: Is your HTML `<form>` containing the `enctype` like `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"`? Can you also try whith escaping the `/` try with: `ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','multipart\/form-data;');`

Comment: Hi @caramba, I didn't use with in the form. I have tried your suggestion but it not working

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that `Content-type: multipart/form-data` should be followed by `boundary: (your file boundary)` but because you set it explicitly it doesn't exist

`Content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryrKBH6bAMJIdepLCI`

If you're not setting `Content-type` then XHR is smart enough to understand that you're sending files, so I suggest you just not to set it or set the `boundary`

(look here [fetch - Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39280438/fetch-missing-boundary-in-multipart-form-data-post))

Comment: Hi @david.lucky, I have tried by setting the boundary value also. but not works. Is boundary value has been updated dynamically by browser?

Comment: How did you set the boundary? Im not sure if you can do it without modifying the content (which I guess you didnt). And also - what's wrong with not setting the content-type and rely on default behaviour?

Comment: What did you mean, "Im not sure if you can do it without modifying the content".

Comment: I mean that this boundary part `------WebKitFormBoundaryrKBH6bAMJIdepLCI
` is used in content to identify file start and file end; so your boundary in content-type should be set according to the content (they should match)