# Can't upload file from angular 5.2 to Laravel 5.5

Tags: angular, laravel-5, file-upload, angular5

I am experiencing a weird behaviour when trying to upload a file from Angular 5.2 to to a Laravel 5.5 application. The file data is not visible/accessible on server side.

I've tried different headers and approaches but they all seem to fail -

**HTML:**

```
<input type="file" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)" multiple/>
```

**JS:**

```
handleFileInput(files: FileList) {
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', files[0], files[0].name);

        let headers = new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json' // also tried 'multipart/form-data' and undefined
        });
        const req = new HttpRequest('POST', 'https://uploader.test/upload', formData, {headers: headers});
        this.http.request(req).subscribe(res => console.log(res)); 
    }
```

**on Laravel side**

`logger('$request', [$request->all()]);`

prints `[]`

Also tried `$request->file('file')` and `Input::file('file')` which both return null.

The Browser's developer tools shows the following payload is submitted:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryqZauUjRcPnD6wRmx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="31562207_10106275826879542_6883202223082307584_n.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryqZauUjRcPnD6wRmx--
```

**UPDATE**
The controller code is really super simple

```
 public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        logger('$request->all()', [$request->all()]);    // prints $request->all() [[]] []
        logger('Input::all()', [Input::all()]);    // prints Input::all() [[]] []
        logger('input.file', [ Input::file('file') ]);    // prints input.file [null] []
        logger('request.file', [ $request->file('file')]);    // prints request.file [null] []
        logger('$_POST', [$_POST]);    // prints $_POST [[]] []
        logger('$_FILES', [$_FILES]);    // prints $_FILES [[]] []
}
```

When I replace formData with an object:

```
const req = new HttpRequest('POST', 'https://uploader.test/upload', {
            data: formData,
            file: files[0],
            test: '123'
        }, {headers: headers});
        this.http.request(req).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

I get `[{"data":[],"file":[],"test":"123"}]`

I've also tried the following workarounds (found in various forums):

- Laravel workaround - `formData.append('_method', 'PUT');`
- using `http.post` instead of `http.request`
- adding options with `contentType: false` and `processData: false`
- Already tried solutions suggested in other questions such as [Angular-5 File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936183/angular-5-file-upload)

In each one of my tests, the file data itself is not being passed on to the server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE 2 - a screenshot of the request headers**
[image]

Comment: judging from the payload you should be getting the file by $request->file, can you add your controller code for laravel side?

Comment: Well files can only be uploaded with `multipart/form-data`, which should be what made you get the browser output, php/laravel should have thus received it, could you share some of the controller code?

Comment: @Hussein updated with controller code, which really just tries to log the request data.

Comment: @Quezler updated with controller code, which really just tries to log the request data.  When I set `multipart/form-data` manually, I get "Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data" error.

Comment: @Yani can you show all the headers that are sent by the request? normally the boundary is set in the header, and should contain `------WebKitFormBoundaryqZauUjRcPnD6wRmx` as value

Comment: @Quezler added a screenshot. Thanks!

Comment: @Yani [apparently if you set the header to `undefined` it just might work for some weird reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39280438/fetch-missing-boundary-in-multipart-form-data-post)

Comment: I have had the same problem, and even Hussein answer solved my problem in local env, however when I moved to production env, I have the same problem, and after long investigation, I came to know that Network Firewall blocks the contents. I am having the same problem in AWS too, uploading the file to EC2

Comment: @dev7, can you look into this question? I think you can answer it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65678554/file-upload-from-angular-9-to-laravel-not-working

Answer (score 2):

let's try this:

for js file handling add this:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable()
export class FileUploader{
  constructor(public http:HttpClient){}

  handleFileInput(files: any){
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let form = new FormData();
    let token = "YOUR_TOKEN";
    form.append('file', files[0], files[0].name);
    xhr.onload = (e) =>{
      console.log('file uploaded');
    };
    xhr.open('POST', "https://uploader.test/upload", true);
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
    xhr.send(form);
  }
}
```

now for laravel side add this:

```
public function saveFile(Request $request){
   $path = $request->file('file')->store('uploaded');
   return response()-json($path);
}
```

in the js code i used the `HttpClient`, you can use `XMLHttpRequest`, try it, if it didn't work let me know

Comment: I'm getting the following error - `Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to a member function store() on null`. The file is not coming through. I removed all middlewares just to make sure and still.

Comment: ok before you send the request can you make sure it's there in the array of `files` ?

Comment: There is - this is what console log prints - `FileList {0: File(59965), length: 1}
0
:
File(59965) {name: "tick_answered.jpeg", lastModified: 1525393170101, lastModifiedDate: Thu May 03 2018 17:19:30 GMT-0700 (PDT), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 59965, …}
length
:
1`

Comment: Yes this works, however it is outside of angular scope and therefore the http interceptors will not run (in charge of adding jwt token and api key). Any idea how to make this work using the http service?

Comment: i edited the answer, you can set any headers you wants through `xhr.setRequestHeader`

Comment: the latest angular version should work with uploading files, check this: https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: Thanks for your replies - I found out that the issue was with the HTTP interceptor overriding the headers and setting `application/json` header. I somehow missed it while debugging. +1 for your help. Your method did help but I wouldn't recommend it to someone who came across this question since the right solution allows using the Http service.Thanks.