# File upload from Angular 9 to Laravel not working

Tags: angular, laravel, file-upload

I am trying to upload image from **angular 9** to **Laravel**.
I configured angular project in my local machine. And Laravel project is in another server. I am using api calls to get data from larvel to angular. All are working fine but File upload is not working.
The request get in server is null.(in usercontroller)
Below is my code:

## Angular

### product.component.html [file upload form]

```
<form [formGroup]="mediaFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="uploadMedia()">
<label>Image:</label>
<input  type="file" name="media_file" (change)="onFileChange($event)" />
<button type="submit" [disabled]="mediaStatus">Upload</button> 
</form>
```

### product.component.ts [file change function and upload function]

```
onFileChange(event) {
if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
this.file = event.target.files[0];
this.thumbFileName = <File>event.target.files[0].name;
var reader = new FileReader();  
reader.onload = (event: any) => {  
      this.thumbUrl = event.target.result;  
}  
reader.readAsDataURL(this.file);  
}
}

uploadMedia(){
const formData = new FormData();
const headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
formData.append('thumbimage', this.file);
this.http.post(`${this.API_URL}/user/uploadImage`, formData, {
      headers: headers
      }).subscribe(data => {
          return data;
      });
}
```

## Laravel

### routes/api.php

```
Route::post('user/uploadImage', "User\UserController@uploadImage");
```

### UserController.php

```
public static function uploadImage(Request $request){
       //return $request;  // null
 if ($request->hasFile('thumbimage'))
 {
       $file      = $request->file('thumbimage');
       $filename  = $file->getClientOriginalName();
       $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
       $picture   = date('His').'-'.$filename;
       $file->move(public_path('tImg'), $picture);
       return response()->json(["message" => "Image Uploaded Succesfully"]);
  }else{
       return response()->json(["message" => "Select image first."]); // returns this
  }
}
```

The **uploadImage** function return *Select image first*

The request is getting as **null** in server.

What is wrong in my code? I think someone can help me..

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. I ended up using the PHP files array.

```
$_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']
```

import this class:

```
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
```

then create a new UploadedFile;

```
$name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
$tempPath = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']
$file = new UploadedFile(
    $tempPath,
    $name,
);

// do other stuff
$original_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
$ext = strtolower($file->getClientOriginalExtension());
$size = $file->getSize();
$type = $file->getMimeType();

$hashName = $file->hashName();
```

If you have multiple files:

```
// $_FILES['filename']['name'] 'An associative array of items uploaded to the 
// current script via the HTTP POST method'
$files = $_FILES['filesarray']
for ($i = 0; $i < count($files['name']); $i++) {
    $name = $files['name'][$i];
    $file = new UploadedFile(
        $files['tmp_name'][$i],
        $name  
    );
    // Do stuff with file
};
```

For more on the PHP $_FILES array check the docs:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when I removed 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' from the http headers.

```
this.httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
         'Accept': 'application/json',
         'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.apiToken
   })
};
```