# File upload in laravel keeps returning null

Tags: php, laravel, upload, xmlhttprequest

This is a file upload request from an angular app:

Request:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryo5BfYJAUkmJC5BoJ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="1570306102797.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryo5BfYJAUkmJC5BoJ--
```

Header:

```
POST /api/recipe HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
Accept: application/json
Host: test.local
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: http://192.168.0.100:8101
Referer: http://192.168.0.100:8101/recipes
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148
Content-Length: 15647436
enctype: multipart/form-data
```

This is my controller in my Laravel app:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
    }
```

No matter what I try I get a null error as if the request doesn't include the "file" image.
Any ideas on how to progress from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what actually in client-side, but try without "Content-Type" in Headers

Comment: Thanks for putting me in the right direction. I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39281156/980711