# Creating form data without using FormData in node-fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, multipartform-data, form-data, node-fetch

- I'm using node fetch to make API Calls inside a platform.
- I need to make an **API Call to pass file in form-data**.
- Below is my stub code:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch")
var myHeaders = {"Authorization": "Basic Y2hhdEJvdDpJRkxjYkAxMjM="
,'cache-control': 'no-cache'
,"content-type": "multipart/form-data;"
};

let file_content = "base 64 file content";

let getFormDataForWhatsAppStatement = (data,fileContent,fileExt)=>{
  let jsonData = { "data":{ "templateName":"Test_123", "fieldName":"Document_Purpose,Policy_Number,Document_Category", "fieldValue":`AttachDocument, ${data.policyNumber}, Customer_Requirement`, "docList":"Test_Doc" } }
  let formDataPairs = [];
  let finalFormData = '';

  formDataPairs.push(encodeURIComponent("") + '=' + encodeURIComponent(jsonData));
  formDataPairs.push(encodeURIComponent("") + '=' + encodeURIComponent(fileContent));

  finalFormData = formDataPairs.join('&').replace(/%20/g, '+');

  return finalFormData;
}

let formdata = getFormData({"policyNumber":"006558144"},file_content,"png");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: formdata
};


fetch(url, requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

- The error I get here is boundary parameter is not defined.
- So I removed the content-type header as stated in the below thread:
  [Boundary Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39280438/fetch-missing-boundary-in-multipart-form-data-post)
- But then it gives me connection timeout error(since the request format is incorrect).
- So is there a way to **create formData Similar to the below code without using FormData Object?**

```
const FormData = require('form-data');
const fetch = require("node-fetch")
var formdata = new FormData();
var myHeaders = {"Authorization": "Basic Y2hhdEJvdDpJRkxjYkAxMjM="
//,"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryyEmKNDsBKjB7QEqu"
};

formdata.append("", "{ \n   \"data\":{ \n\n      \"templateName\":\"Test_123\",\n      \"fieldName\":\"Document_Purpose,Policy_Number,Document_Category\",\n      \"fieldValue\":\"AttachDocument, G0000784, Customer_Requirement\",\n      \"docList\":\"Test_Doc\"  \n}\n}\n");
formdata.append("", "base 64 file data", "close.png");
var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: formdata,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch(API_URL, requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of literally inputting the boundary have you tried using the form-data function getBoundary() and assigning it to a variable like so:

```
let boundary = formdata.getBoundary();
var myHeaders = {"Authorization": "Basic Y2hhdEJvdDpJRkxjYkAxMjM="
"Content-Type": `multipart/form-data; boundary=${boundary}`
};
```