# uploading a file via API, multipart/form-data

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, http-post

**I'm using rembg in my app:**
https://github.com/danielgatis/rembg

**What i want to do**
Upload a image to my API endpoint using http.post;

**Running this code:**

```
this.photoService.readFile(this.publicImageUrl.uri).then(res => {

let data = res;
this.oryginalImg = data.data;

this.ApiService.removeBG(this.publicImageUrl.uri).then(res => console.log(res))

})
```

**readFile():**

```
async readFile(path: string) {
  const contents = await Filesystem.readFile({
  path: path
});

return contents;
}
```

**removeBG():**

```
  async removeBG(file: any) {

  let headers = { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' };
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file);

  let body = {
    'body': formData
   }


   let promise = new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post(environment.photoServiceURL, body, { headers }).toPromise().then(res => { console.log(res); resolve(); }).catch(err => console.log(err));
});

  }
```

**Response is:**
Missing boundary in multipart.

**Request:**

It's look like there's something wrong with attaching a file, am I right? How to attach file from filesystem and upload this file via API?

Comment: Try `this.http.post(environment.photoServiceURL,formData, { headers }).toPromise().then(res => { console.log(res); resolve(); }).catch(err => console.log(err));` Add FormData as the body OR a JSON object. A FormData inside a JSON will be throw your error.

Comment: @flo unfortunately the same, still getting error.

Comment: @flo, are you replying to me? :)

Comment: No, sorry... wrong tab :-)

Comment: Try it without to set the header `content-type` this will angular do automatically. Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39280438/fetch-missing-boundary-in-multipart-form-data-post

Comment: Looks like it helped, but i think i got problem with attaching files: 
[HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request 119ms]

1

-----------------------------338325175014467820091313680227
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"
/DATA/1669547487808.jpeg
-----------------------------338325175014467820091313680227--
" There's no file content, only URI to file, and angular didn't recognize filetype

Answer (score 1):

If you using @capacitor/filesystem you need to to the follow:

```
const response = await fetch(file.data); // where file comes from Filesystem.readFile
const blob = await response.blob();
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', blob, file.name);

// ...then upload your form as above
```

You need to fetch the data of your given file, get the blob and then set the FormData.
[Here](https://devdactic.com/ionic-image-upload-capacitor) is a example from Ionic.

Greetings, Flo

Comment: Flo, we are closer! i used     const dataToBlob = `data:image/${oryginalFileExt};base64,${oryginalImgData}`;
and i get finally that I want to get - attached file :-)