# loopback - Upload files from another model

Tags: node.js, api, storage, loopbackjs

I have two models:

**container**:
handles file uploading and works fine in loopback explorer.

**Crawler**:
have multiple properties. one of the properties is `script` that user can upload a script file to this model.

`crawler.json`:

```
{
  "name": "Crawler",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "script": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "startCount": {
      "type": "number",
      "default": 0
    },
    "created_at": {
      "type": "date"
    },
    "updated_at": {
      "type": "date"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

`crawler.js`:

```
module.exports = function(Crawler) {
  Crawler.upload = function (id,req,res,cb) {
    var container = Crawler.app.models.container;
    container.getContainers(function(er,containers){
      console.log(containers);
      if (containers.some(function(e){return e.name == 'script';})) {
        container.upload(req,res,{container:"script"},cb);
      }else{
        container.createContainer({name: "script"}, function(er,c){
          container.upload(req,res,{container: "script"},cb);
        });
      }
    });
  Crawler.remoteMethod(
    'upload',
    {
      description: 'Uploads a script',
      accepts: [
        { arg: 'id', type: 'string', http: {source: 'path'}},
        { arg: 'req', type: 'object', http: { source:'req' } },
        { arg: 'res', type: 'object', http:{ source: 'res'} }
      ],
      returns: {
        arg: 'crawler', type: 'Crawler', root: true
      },
      http: {path: '/:id/script',verb: 'post'}
    }
  );
};
```

but the *problem* is when I run `POST /Crawlers/:id/script`, program freeze on `container.upload(...)` function and does not return anything. after a while, the request will be aborted due to timeout.

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28885282/how-to-store-files-with-meta-data-in-loopback) on StackOverflow but the same problem happens there too.

What happens to `upload` function? are the parameters passed to `upload` correct? is there any workaround? is there any solution for uploading files other than `loopback-component-storage`?

(my node version is 6.7.0 and loopback 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, you should use body-parser middleware like this:

```
"parse": {
    "body-parser#json": {},
    "body-parser#urlencoded": {"params": { "extended": true }}
}
```

BTW files are sent in an array like this: `fileObject.files[null]`